# Converting JSON to POJO and throw exception in case of null value for required field

Tags: java, json

I want to convert a JSON into POJO(i.e. class) and a class that has some field annotated with @Notnull. Converting that JSON into POJO, but if JSON has a null value for a required field in that case object mapper should throw an exception.

I do not know, what I am doing mistake in this, please help me.

Class:-

```
public class Abc {
    @NotNull
    private String id;
    @NotNull
    private String entityType;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEntityType() {
        return entityType;
    }

    public void setEntityType(String entityType) {
        this.entityType = entityType;
    }

}
Public class Demo{
  public static void main(String []args){
      String data="{ \"supportEntitySpecification.id\":\"an001\", \"supportEntityType\":null }";
      Abc abc= objectMapper.readValue(data),
                    Abc.class);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@NotNull` is an annotation. Annotations do nothing on their own. See these as Documentation.

Your can use `ConstraintValidator` for example to valid your Object with annotations: [ConstraintValidator](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.html)